# Can't get async and await working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

Logic says: User 1 sends a message to User 2 via Server 1. Server 1 records it in DB (mysql) and sends the message to Server 2 to be sent to User 2. Server 1 responds to User 1 that message has been sent. While at the back-end (asynchonously) Server 1 keeps requesting Server 2 for the delivery of the message, when delivered, updates the database and set delivery status as delivered or failed (after few hours of re-trying).

But I don't think this code is working. Because database never gets updated.

SendMessage.aspx

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    global g = new global();
    g.CallUpdateSMSStatus(cmdSMS.LastInsertedId.ToString(), msgID);
}
```

global.cs

```
    public async void CallUpdateSMSStatus(string strMsgID, string strMsgID)
    {
        await updateMessageStatus(strMsgID, strMsgIDServer);
    }

    public async Task updateMessageStatus(string strMsgID, string strMsgID)
    {
        global g = new global();
        int timer = 10000;
        int intStatus = 2;
        // 2 - means Message Sent - Any other number finishes delivery request
        while (intStatus == 2)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                intStatus = g.checkSMSStatus(strMsgIDServer);
                //checkSMSStatus REQUEST SERVER 2 for status of message
                if (intStatus != 2)
                {
                    //Update Status in the Database 
                }
                else
                {
                    if (timer < 3600000)
                    {
                        timer *= 10;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(timer);

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Because database never gets updated.` Can you show us the code that updates the database?

Comment: Why are you calling ``global g = new global();`` in Code that you say is in ``global.cs`` shouldnt you be working with ``this``?

Comment: And what does work here. Does the other user receive the message?

Comment: @mjwills I can give the code but it is working (reason I didn't think it would be required) because the database IS updated with status 2 (i.e. Message Sent). Let me know if you still want code.

Comment: You have an `async void` method. That's a giant red flag. Don't do that! Always return a `Task` or `Task<T>` unless you are writing an event handler called by the framework.

Comment: @RandRandom oh yes. I actually copied few lines from another file (my own code) but started concentrating on async and await. I'll make it 'this'. No problem.

Comment: To extend on @mason 's comment you should actually mark the ``Click`` event ``async`` and call ``await g.updateMessageStatus()`` and drop the ``CallUpdateSMSStatus`` method

Comment: @Chrono yes they are receiving message that too within couple of seconds. When I manually check the status, it says delivered.

Comment: @mason ok. but then do i need another function `updateMessageStatus` or I can replace its code within `CallUpdateSMSStatus`'s body ??

Comment: @RandRandom I tried that first, but then I had to add ` Async="true"` in the `@ Page` directive and its not working.

Comment: Didnt realise the asp.net tag, never used the async/await pattern there and dont know if there are limitations. sorry.

Comment: @VAThomas You don't need two methods that have the same signature.

Comment: Does this actually work if you remove all the async modifiers?

Comment: @mason If I omit the `CallUpdateSMSStatus`, I have to use `await` in the `btnSend_Click` method, and then I have to make `btnSend_Click` async which it shouldn't be.

Comment: Yes, it should be. Did you see Rand Random's comment above?

Comment: @user6144226 YES, it does.

Comment: @mason wouldn't that affect rest of the synchronous code ? I'm trying though.

Comment: No. But anyways, this is all pointless. If your button click takes more than a second or two, then async-ifying this isn't going to be much difference. What you should really do is queue up a background job.

Comment: @mason here's what I changed as you said,
Changed definition to skip Call... method:
`public async Task updateSMSStatus`

Changed event handler definition
`protected async void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`

to call 
`await g.updateSMSStatus(cmdSMS.LastInsertedId.ToString(), msgID);`

had to change page directive to
`Async="true"`
I changed timer= 100000 (100s) to see the affect. It ran for complete 100s before giving me Message Sent acknowledgement. 
Conclusion, it worked correctly BUT SYNCHRONOUSLY.

Comment: Which is part of my point. You need to queue this up in the background. If it takes 100 seconds, it shouldn't be happening directly in a button click handler. See [How to run background tasks in ASP.NET](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you want:

```
public async Task updateMessageStatus(string strMsgID, string strMsgIDServer, int timeToNext)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        global g = new global();

        int intStatus = g.checkSMSStatus(strMsgIDServer);
        //checkSMSStatus REQUEST SERVER 2 for status of message
        if (intStatus != 2)
        {
            //Update Status in the Database
        }
        else
        if (timeToNext < 3600000)
            Task.Delay(timeToNext).ContinueWith((t) => updateMessageStatus(strMsgID, strMsgIDServer, timeToNext * 10));
    });
}
```

Comment: a bit explanation. So that I can integrate the code properly. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't this implementation stop waiting after the timer reaches 1h? I do think OP's just waits indefinetely maxing out at 1h intervals

Comment: @user6144226 if the function called with 1000 in timeToNext parameter, the first try delay 10000 first call, the 2-try delay 100000 and 3-try delay 1000000, and after that stop. as the OP code.

Comment: @lomed timing and delay are not the concerned, they are working fine synchronously. I can't get it worked as asyncly.
This code worked too but syncly.

Comment: @AVAThomas  can you explain "bottom line" what you expect with the code ? Because for me an synchronous\asynchronous is an abstract theme.

Comment: @lomed I would request you to please read the logic again. In short, I want to respond to the user that the message has been sent (delivered or not doesn't matter), and at the back end, the server keeps on requesting the other server for the status (delivered or not, delivery report that is) and update that status as is. Failure (not delivered after a few requests).

Comment: @lomed my code is working if I run without async and await.